# Lua crashes on lua_getglobal

Tags: c++, lua, crash

So I have this problem.

In my program I have a class (LuaScript) which handles lua scripts for me. However I'm running into a bit of a problem when calling lua functions. I have a C++ function called callFunction which works like this:

```
void LuaScript::callFunction(const std::string& functionName)
{
     lua_getglobal(state, "update");

     if (lua_pcall(state, 0, 0, 0))
         printf("Error calling lua function: %s\n", lua_tostring(state, -1));
}
```

But it crashes (which I found out after some debugging) on the `lua_getglobal` bit but it doesn't crash the first time I call the function (which has me believing that the lua_State* somehow is corrupt) and through even more debugging I get this error message from VS:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x006CBADA (lua5.1.dll)
Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDED.
```

FYI, my lua source looks like this:

```
function update()
    print("Hello")
end
```

I have no idea what do to

Comment: have you verified that `state` is not NULL inside `callFunction`? If you `print("Hello")`, does it work? when you say it crashes only second time you call "update", do you mean that the first time succeeded without any errors? Try replacing the print statement by `return 123`, what happens? Please mention if first or second function call.

Comment: Where is state coming from in that function? What is happening in your application before you call your update function the first time? Between the first and second times?